# Give an example of a function that is infinitely differentiable and that vanishes off the interval $[-a,a]$

Tags: calculus, derivatives

Give an example of a function that is infinitely differentiable and that vanishes off the interval $[-a,a]$

I think $y=0$ satisfies this problem. Is this true?

Comment: Yes, the function $y=0$ satisfies those conditions.

Comment: Is $0$ infinitely differentiable. Does it vanish off that interval?

Comment: For a non-trivial example see [the bump function](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bump_function).